# Button sends you to NavigationDrawerFragment activity using android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I am trying to link a button to another activity but the second activity is NavigationDrawerFragment. It's not working for me.

This is the code executed when the button is clicked:

```
public void onClickListener(){
Button goToSaying=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    goToSaying.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = new 
          Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2Activity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

When you create a new NavigationDrawerFragment Activity, it is creating two actions (NavigationDrawerFragment) and (MainActivity2Activity) automatically.

In that code i was trying to call (MainActivity2Activity) which is the main activity for the drawer. However there are a lot of errors appearing. I have tried this code to call a simple activity and it is working, but for the drawer i don't know what is the problem.

Please help me.